# Sailsjs 0.10.x : How to run the production grunt tasks for a staging environment

Tags: sails.js

Sails.js 0.10x: I added an new file "staging.js" to the config/env folder.

Starting the server with `>sails lift --staging` shows that the staging file was used.

But it still uses the development grunt tasks. e.g. no minification, dev blueprint settings, etc.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to run the the prod grunt tasks with a new environment like staging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `sails` node module of your application, you can navigate to the Grunt lib file (`app_base/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js`). If you look at the code there, under the `initialize` method, there's a condition to check if the environment is the production environment and calls the production Grunt task. Even though you could edit this condition to include your staging environment, this file isn't meant to be altered - updating the module in the future would erase any changes you make.

The best thing to do would be to go to `app_base/tasks/register/prod.js` and move your staging environment tasks to be run at prod and just use the prod environment. Alternatively, you could copy the production tasks over to your staging environment tasks.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I ended up doing. Just using prod and dev. instead of more staging config file I use env variables to inject parameters like connection strings, keys, etc.